How can I bypass an input prompt for an extension command in VS Code when running the command as part of a task?
I'm trying to automate the process of turning a Dendron note into a pdf.
Since there isn't currently native support for exporting to pdf, I'm using pandoc to convert markdown to a pdf.
However, before I can run pandoc, I need to convert/transpile the special Dendron metadata and tags to generic markdown.
I'm trying to accomplish this in a single step by writing a custom VS code task (actually a sequence of two tasks) that first does the export to markdown and then runs pandoc in the command line to convert the generic markdown into a pdf.
The problem I'm running into is that I can't find a way to bypass the user input prompt that dendron.exportPodv2 returns to ask which export configuration it should use.
I was hoping that entering the id of the configuration as an argument for the command would work, but it doesn't seem to.
Here is my tasks.json:
{
"version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Build to PDF",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "./assets/scripts/pdf.cmd",
      "group": "build",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new",
        "clear": true,
        "close": true
      },
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "dependsOn": [
        "Export to generic Markdown"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Export to generic Markdown",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${command:dendron.exportPodv2}",
      "args": [
        "coop-md" //'coop-mid' is the id of the configuration that I want it to use when running dendron.exportPodv2
      ],
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "new",
        "clear": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}


Does anyone know how to programmatically bypass a user input prompt in a vs code task?
